# Is there a way to pull a list of apps on an android phone?

Tags: android, list, android-studio, pull, android-appstandby

So a bit of backstory as to what i'm trying to do. I'm working on an idea for an app which can scan what apps are on your phone, the bar codes of groceries and other things and display information on what environmental impact they have.

So what i'm trying to do is see if there is a way to pull a list of all the installed apps of an android phone, and for me to then be able to match these apps up with information I will gather (still figuring that bit out).

I'm working in android studio and had a look through the forums here but the ones I found weren't really what I was looking for because they specified running apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can get information about installed apps via PackageManager

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

[See docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for thanks

Comment: @DarrenGillespie than you may accept the answer